# vsts.agent | add capability key-pair | how to access capability value in VSTS build definition | webpack with hosted agent

Tags: webpack

I am using latest vsts.agent agent.version 2.107.0 . Sure it resolved a lot of issues associated to security execution context and I can now happily run Azure RM taks and any PowerShell task. However, there is a remaining issue that I could not figure out, is how to acess the key-pair value entered in a pool agenty capability.

If capability is defined as: webpack = c:\NPM\Modules\webpack.cmd , which is what I figured out when poking around when using HOST agent when building a webpack bundler, I cannot access the path value by simply using $(webpac) or other similar syntax. Nowhere is this documeneted and did not find any example.

Should $(webpac) not simply work? is it a bug?

Btw, if someone is interested to know how I did include webpack'ing in the build definition, I'll be happy to share it here. Does works with custom build servers as well as with the Hosted agent.

Thanks. Cheers.